# Need help to enable the sorting and pagination on the elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am relatively new to elastic search. I am trying to enable the pagination and sorting on the following ES query having multiple aggregations. I tried composite agg, it didnt help on sorting. Following is the query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "customerId.keyword": "{{customerId_value}}"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*{{search_query}}*",
            "minimum_should_match": "75%",
            "fields": [
              "neName.keyword^3",
              "productFamily.keyword^2",
              "productId.keyword^2",
              "ipAddress.keyword^2",
              "swVersion.keyword^2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "lastReset": {
              "to": "now",
              "from": "{{range}}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_devices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "neInstanceId.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "device_stats": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "lastReset"
          }
        },
        "required_fields": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "neInstanceId",
                "neName",
                "productFamily",
                "productId",
                "swVersion",
                "ipAddress",
                "serialNumber"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

expectation: pagination and sorting on all fields. Appreciate any response.

Comment: Should I use ES data frames to acheive ?

Comment: Did you check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size for pagination and for https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-sort for sorting? If so, could you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve ( with example ), what you tried the problems you are trying to resolve?